# Newbie: Unable to Install Homebrew on MacOS

Tags: ios, react-native, homebrew, macos-catalina

I have been having certain issues while trying to setup my Mac (OS:Catalina) for a React Native Development.

I have read multiple guides and tutorials as I am facing issues initializing a react native build (react-native init). I keep getting err lifecycle validation

Multiple articles suggest to download Homebrew and it might solve a lot of the issues related to package folders for node etc.

When I try installing Homebrew using the below link -

```
/usr/bin/ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"
```

I get a message on my terminal :
Curl: (7) Couldn't connect to server.

If I try to type in the address on the browser, I get the installation code which I saved on the Mac storage as install.rb
Entering '/usr/bin/Ruby install' throws a prompt that the folder doesn't exist.

I already have Xcode and Xcode Command Line Tools installed.

I would appreciate any help I can get on how I can just prepare my system for learning react native development for iOS.
I am at a bit of 'no clue what I am doing wrong'   phase.

Comment: does `npx react-native init PROJECT_NAME` work for you?

Answer (score 0):

**Try this command on terminal**

```
ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"
```

Comment: Thank you for the response. I tried it just now. I copy pasted the syntax that you mentioned directly on the terminal but I still got the couldn't connect to server issue. I am connected to the internet in general

Comment: I have this guide/tutorial open which I was also trying to follow but I am stuck at the first point (Homebrew installation) itself.  https://medium.com/@pabasarajayawardhana/react-native-environment-set-up-on-mac-os-with-xcode-and-android-studio-324e64c8552e

Comment: Ouch. I guess this is something that is just as issue with my machine then or maybe some conflicting fields.